# Tremulous with unlimited building: Should aliens focus on destroying nodes or repeaters after destroying the human reactor?

Tags: tremulous

When the alien team destroys the [human reactor](http://tremulous.net/manual/#x1-100002.2.3), and there is a limited time before humans rebuild, what's a better tactic - focusing on destroying nodes or repeaters?

By killing nodes, aliens have a chance of winning right away, and low node count slows down spawning humans, making it harder for them to defend.

By killing repeaters, aliens make surrounding human buildings non-functional, even after humans build a new reactor, which makes it easy to destroy later, but spawned humans can rebuild the repeaters and defend the other buildings.